# How can I stop my printer from printing a test page after every turnon?

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, hp-photosmart

I have a HP Photosmart C3180 and Windows 10. The color ink cartridge is empty and I do not want to replace it because I never use color anyway. The thing is, since I replaced my black ink cartridge, my printer automatically prints a test page after every single turnon, which is totally annoying and wastes black ink. How can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: It's an option in the printer settings. Have you checked the printer settings at all? Did you scan the test page to verify the alignment of the printout? http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/Printer-printing-test-page-every-time-I-turn-it-on/td-p/162143

Comment: I believe the printer wants to be calibrated. When a new cartridge is installed it prints the calibration test page to check that it is aligned properly. Unfortunately, as your colour cartridge is empty, the alignment will always be faulty, so I suspect there is no fix for this.

Comment: @TJJ of course I have checked the settings. Which setting in particular do you mean? And I do not want to align anything, it just needs to stop trying.

Comment: See if the suggestion here helps,, by a HP employee: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/Printer-printing-test-page-every-time-I-turn-it-on/td-p/162143/page/3

Comment: @Felix Dombek: Ah, I owe you a small apology. We HAD an HP printer at my office, was switched now to a Xerox. The Xerox printed a test page whenever you turned it on. There was an option on the settings to stop that. But it seems like those HP All-In-One need to scan the test page after installing cartridge to verify the alignment.

Comment: And because your colour cartridge is empty, alignment will always fail.

Comment: @hdhondt That's true. I still think a decent printer should have an option for that. Or some kind of hotfix or alternative driver or firmware or ...

But none of that seems to exist.

Comment: See if you can get HP to fix it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the printer wants to be calibrated. When a new cartridge is installed it prints the calibration test page to check that it is aligned properly. With many HP printers you need to then scan the test page, so the printer can set itself up correctly.

Unfortunately, as your colour cartridge is empty, the alignment will always be faulty, so I suspect there is no fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and @hdhondt's answer pointed me in the right direction.

It may seem obvious, but make sure you press the BLACK copy button when scanning the calibration page if you installed a new black cartridge. I had pressed the color button the first time around with the assumption that it doesn't matter which copy button is used.